# Excel grab data from MS SQL Server with WHERE clause based on cell contents

Tags: sql-server, excel

There's a bunch of questions for similar things, but I've been unable to find anything that fits.

We have three columns:

`Name   |    ID    |    Cost
Thingy       3          25
Other        11         5`

Only ID is manually entered. Name and cost on that row are then fetched automatically from an MSSQL database.

I've been looking at using Microsoft Query data source with `?` in the WHERE clause to then add parameters based on cell contents but firstly, the parameters button is greyed out and secondly, even if it worked, it seems like I'd need to manually create queries for every single row with cell reference hardcoded in rather than one cell query that could be replicated down the name and cost columns.

Any guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: If you are able to connect to your SQL Server, but need help tweaking the query, that would be an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.  Here on DBA.StackExchange, basic SQL questions are generally off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you make a tab in your sheet that holds all of your SQL data?  Each time you load your sheet you could refresh this data to make it fresh then everything else could be an Excel formula (lookup on SQL tab) to get at what you want.  My reason for suggesting this is you sound a lot more familiar with Excel over MS Query.

Otherwise in MS Query use your table as a data source and join with the SQL data (again I'd probably throw the result in a new tab)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's kind of the system already in place (just using a separate file instead of a separate tab). The problem is, the Excel formula to look up the value has to specify the region of the sheet to search in (essentially defining a box by columns and rows) and as more database rows are added to the table, the larger the search area becomes, which requires the lookup formula in each cell to be manually adjusted to search a larger area.

Comment: Also, so you don't get the wrong idea, my Excel knowledge is actually really basic (I'm fine with SQL) so there's probably a lot of functionality here I'm totally unaware of.

Comment: Re my first comment ^ it did occur to me that I could just set the searchable area as something huge. Other than potential performance impact is there any reason I shouldn't do that?

Comment: If you are better with SQL then joining the data using mssql would be your best bet.

Comment: This is actually a really solid suggestion so I've selected it as best answer. I did what I mentioned above with setting the search area of the sheet to a huge number (so not perfect but seems to work fine). Many thanks Matt!